# FMDB not working in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

In my project I added FMDB using cocoapods. I then created a bridging header for FMDB. But when I import FMDB.h using `#import "FMDB.h"` I receive the error "FMDB.h not found".
When I import "#import " from folder, Xcode again gives me errors for importing inside FMDB framework files: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module (module name)"

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that none of the FM...h files were even in the folder being used by the code. Once I put them there, it worked.

If you highlight the FMDB.h file in the project navigator, you will see the path being searched for the files in the upper right corner of the screen under "Identity and Type" called "Full Path". If you check that physical location, you will likely find that the files are not there to be found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbIZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the **Build Settings** tab under the "Target" and set `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` to YES.

If that doesn't work, try selecting the `FMDB.h` file in the project navigator. In the target membership area on the right there is a drop down menu next to the target. Select "Public" there.  It may be set to "Project" right now.

Hope that helps!

Comment: import this way " #import <FMDB/FMDB.h>"

Comment: @Charlie Yes, Correct.